# Not able to get value from div using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm missing something obvious here.  A pic is worth 10k words.  These are some screenshots from a DOM debug in Chrome.

HTML:

[image]

Looking at the script, paused in debug:

[image]

Why is `ammount` not populating?  (Ignore the misspelling of `ammount`... I'll fix it!!)

Comment: Because you should use `.text()` or `.html()` for non-input DOM elements

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**`.val()`** is for *form inputs*, not text inside of divs. You can get the amount using **`.text()`** or **`.html()`** in place of val.